# Call to undefined method App\Models\User::()

Tags: laravel

can someone has an idea of this error

[image]

I try to join 2 tables which is the user and employee table using hasOne eloquent
the purpose for this is to authenticate employee information also.

this is my database

Employee Table
[image]

Users Table
[image]

this is my User Model

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $fillable = [
    'empID',
    'email',
    'userType',
    'user_created',
    'status',
    'password',
];
    public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::class,'empID', 'empID');
}
```

and my Employee Model

```
    protected $table = 'employee';
protected $fillable = [
    'empID',
    'avatar',
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'email',
    'role',
    'department',
    'empStatus',
    'phoneName',
];
    public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,'empID', 'empID');
}
```

my controller Employee

```
    public function listAllEmployee()
{
    // $employees = Employee::all();
    $employees  = Auth::user()->employee()->get();
    $role = DB::table('role_type')->get();
    $department = DB::table('departments')->get();
    
    return view('employee.employeelist', [
        'employees'   => $employees,
        'role'  => $role,
        'department'    => $department,
    ]);
}
```

My blade view

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown has-arrow main-drop">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="user-img">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/assets/images/'. Auth::user()->avatar) }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->lname }}">
                <span class="status online"></span></span>
                <span>{{ Auth::user()->fname() }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Profile</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: `Auth::user()->fname()` - where did you define `fname`?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `Auth::user()->employee()->fname()` instead?

Comment: `fname` seems to be a property, not a method, `Auth::user()->employee->fname` should work

Comment: i already try Auth::user()->employee()->fname but new error occur it says,

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::fname()

Comment: Right, `Auth::user()->employee->fname` then?

Comment: @brombeer i already try this but i get this new error 

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::fname()

Comment: `Auth::user()->employee->fname` not `Auth::user()->employee()->fname`, the `->employee()` returns a Query Builder (you can use it to add query methods like `->where`), using `->employee` returns the `Employee` entity.

Comment: i already try this Auth::user()->employee->fname but still same errors

Answer (score 0):

The error you presented is telling you that no method called `fname()` exists in the `User` Model, meaning that you are trying to access that method while you should be trying to access the property `fname` by using `Auth::user()->employee->fname`.

Model database columns are accessable as properties, not methods, these are reserved for relations & custom methods.

Comment: I see, so the hasOne did not function right?

Comment: The `hasOne` should be correct, my answer was for explaining what the difference is between methods and properties. Methods are methods that you current have in your Entity (relations & custom methods), properties are used to access the database column related to that model (`fname` column in DB is accessed by using `$employee->fname`).